# [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client at new NodeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, axios, node-modules

I'm getting this error and I'dont know where I'm wrong

> node:internal/errors:478 ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err); ^ Error
> [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to
> the client at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5) at
> ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:644:11) at
> ServerResponse.header
> (/var/task/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:10) at
> ServerResponse.send
> (/var/task/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:174:12) at
> /var/task/index.js:47:17 at processTicksAndRejections
> (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) { code:
> 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT' }

I tried

```js
scrapeIt("http://www.mumresults.in/", {
            program: ".prgno",
        }).then(({ data, status }) => {
            console.log(`Status Code: ${status}`)
            res.send(data.program)

                if (data.program.includes('1T01437')) {
                axios
                    .post("https://demoapi.com/", { name: "Result Declared", email: "demo@gmail.com" })
                    .then(({ data }) => {
                        console.log(data)
                    })
                    .catch((e) => {
                        console.log(e)
                    });
            }
        });
```

Comment: It's because `res.send(data.program)` but not only that. Your code (the request tree) has some other place that uses `res.send`. You have to send one response back.